# Poor CNN performance after implementing BatchNormalization

Tags: neural-network, cnn, batch-normalization

I am training a CNN to classify malware images from a dataset named Malimg. Before implementing the BatchNormalization layer, I was getting an accuracy of 95.57% (see below for the graph of loss/accuracy and validation loss/accuracy):
[image: accuracy]
[image: loss]

```
Epoch 1/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 53s 8ms/step - loss: 1.7711 - accuracy: 0.4605 - val_loss: 1.0062 - val_accuracy: 0.6510
Epoch 2/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 52s 8ms/step - loss: 0.8739 - accuracy: 0.7150 - val_loss: 0.4965 - val_accuracy: 0.8426
Epoch 3/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 52s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5163 - accuracy: 0.8406 - val_loss: 0.3061 - val_accuracy: 0.9136
Epoch 4/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 54s 8ms/step - loss: 0.3656 - accuracy: 0.8897 - val_loss: 0.1989 - val_accuracy: 0.9408
Epoch 5/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 53s 8ms/step - loss: 0.3063 - accuracy: 0.9016 - val_loss: 0.1822 - val_accuracy: 0.9490
Epoch 6/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 52s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2657 - accuracy: 0.9166 - val_loss: 0.1886 - val_accuracy: 0.9472
Epoch 7/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 52s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2366 - accuracy: 0.9237 - val_loss: 0.1618 - val_accuracy: 0.9536
Epoch 8/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 52s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2071 - accuracy: 0.9315 - val_loss: 0.1341 - val_accuracy: 0.9615
Epoch 9/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 52s 8ms/step - loss: 0.2017 - accuracy: 0.9330 - val_loss: 0.1424 - val_accuracy: 0.9618
Epoch 10/10
6537/6537 [==============================] - 51s 8ms/step - loss: 0.1882 - accuracy: 0.9362 - val_loss: 0.1425 - val_accuracy: 0.9557
2802/2802 [==============================] - 9s 3ms/step
```

After implementing BatchNormalization, my results were very poor, and the model was all over the place (see below the results). Is there any reason for this? I am aware of what BatchNormalization does and that it stabilises the learning process and can help the neural network's performance, but I was advised to implement it.

Below is the code (of the neural network) and the results after implementing BatchNormalization:

```
num_classes = 25 #the amount of outputs in the output class
model-x = Sequential()
model-x.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,64,3)))
model-x.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model-x.add(BatchNormalization())
model-x.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model-x.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model-x.add(Dropout(0.25))
model-x.add(Flatten())
model-x.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model-x.add(Dropout(0.5))
model-x.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model-x.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model-x.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


y_train_new = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_train_new), y_train_new)

history = model-x.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10,  class_weight=class_weights)
scores = model-x.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

model-x.summary()
```

[image: accuracy - after batchnorm]
[image: loss - after batchnorm]

**Updated results after suggestion**
[image: accuracy - after suggestion]
[image: loss- after suggestion]

**Code after suggestion**

```
num_classes = 25 #the amount of outputs in the output class

model-x = Sequential()

model-x.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(64,64,3)))
model-x.add(BatchNormalization())
model-x.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model-x.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model-x.add(BatchNormalization())
model-x.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model-x.add(Dropout(0.25))
model-x.add(Flatten())
model-x.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model-x.add(Dropout(0.5))
model-x.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model-x.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model-x.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

y_train_new = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_train_new), y_train_new)

history = model-x.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10,  class_weight=class_weights)
scores = model-x.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

model-x.summary()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the BatchNorm after a MaxPool. It is always applied after Convolution layers not Pooling layers. Hence, your network is acting like this.

Put BatchNorm after all Conv layers.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your suggestion. I made changes (can be seen in the question now under the bold text). This produces very peculiar results too.

Comment: Remove dropout after maxpool and keep dropout probability in between 0.1 and 0.3.

Comment: I will try and get back to you with the results. Is there by reason for removing dropout after maxpool and changing the probability?

Comment: the results were not different and again very skewed even after your suggestion.

Comment: You have very simple images. Start with a single conv layer with batch norm followed by a flatten and finally dense. No dropouts initially. Work with the kernel size, try 3 first then 5. Start from this, then, work incrementally. Also, read research papers on this dataset what they have done. See this dataset on paperswithcode.